# Fisher's exact test on rows in data frame - R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data frame of n rows that resembles below (with some extra columns containing additional information not listed):

```
           R1counti    R1counto     R2counti    R2counto    R1    R2
sample1    100         100          1000        1000        1     1
smaple2    50          100          50           50         0.5   1
```

For each row, I want to perform a fisher's exact test to determine if the R1 ratio is significantly different from the R2 ratios (and also in the end get an adjusted p-val)

Desired output (with the count columns still included in the out):

```
           R1    R2      pval
 sample1   1     1       1
 sample2   0.5   1       0.05
```

I thought I could do something like:

```
dataframe$p-val <- with(dataframe, p-val <- fisher.test(R1, R2, alternative= "two.sided"))
```

But I get an error:

```
FEXACT error 40.
Out of workspace.
```

Maybe I'm not handling this situation correctly. Any advice? Suggestions? Can I perform a fishers test like this?

Comment: Have a look at `?fisher.test`, it expects counts not pre-computed ratios. Ratios themselves do not provide enough information to run Fisher's exact test, as they don't convey the sample size. There's a big difference between a 2/4 = 0.5 ratio and a 500/1000 = 0.5 ratio.

Comment: @Gregor I also have the count data for R1 and R2 in the file. I'm just unsure how I could perform the test using using this dataframe.

Comment: an edit was made to show the counts in the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each row of your dataset you need to build a matrix (i.e. a 2 x 2 contingency table) and pass this matrix to the `fisher.test` command.

```
df <- read.table(text="
          R1counti    R1counto     R2counti    R2counto    R1    R2
sample1    100         100          1000        1000        1     1
sample2    50          100          50           50         0.5   1
", header=T, row.names=1)


apply(df, 1, 
      function(x) {
          tbl <- matrix(as.numeric(x[1:4]), ncol=2, byrow=T)
          fisher.test(tbl, alternative="two.sided")$p.value
      })

#    sample1    sample2 
# 1.00000000 0.01209383
```